# Get the email address of a Microsoft user

Tags: passport.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-account

I want to add a `login with Microsoft` button to my mean-stack application. So I am using [passport-microsoft](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-microsoft).

By using `passport.authenticate('microsoft', { scope: ['User.Read'] })`, I could get these information: `@odata.context`, `givenName`, `surname`, `displayName` `id`, `userPrincipalName`, `businessPhones`, `jobTitle`, `mail`, `mobilePhone`, `officeLocation`, `preferredLanguage`. For me, my `userPrincipalName` is an email address, whereas my `mail` is `null`.

I have setup the application as follows, but if I write `passport.authenticate('microsoft', { scope: ['User.Read', 'email'] })`, the authentication gave me an "invalid scope" error.

[image]

Does anyone know how to setup my application and request to get the email address of a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for the `user` object](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user), you will find the following:

> **mail**
>
> > *String*
> >
> > The SMTP address for the user, for example,
> >     "jeff@contoso.onmicrosoft.com". Read-Only. Supports $filter.

> **userPrincipalName**
>
> > String
> >
> > The user principal name (UPN) of the user. The UPN is an
> >     Internet-style login name for the user based on the Internet standard
> >     RFC 822. **By convention, this should map to the user's email name.** The
> >     general format is alias@domain, where domain must be present in the
> >     tenant’s collection of verified domains. This property is required
> >     when a user is created. The verified domains for the tenant can be
> >     accessed from the verifiedDomains property of organization. Supports
> >     $filter and $orderby.

So it seems the `mail` property does not necessarily represent the email address for the user, but is used specifically with Outlook and Office 365. It is also not a required property when creating a user. Instead, you should rely on the `userPrincipalName` to be the email for the user.

As for your error with the scope, you should share the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Console log the *profile* object within the verify function to see it's shape and properties. The user's email should be accessible as *profile._json.userPrincipalName*.

```
//Modified example from documentation (source: https://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-microsoft/):

    var MicrosoftStrategy = require('passport-microsoft').Strategy;
    passport.use(new MicrosoftStrategy({
        clientID: 'applicationidfrommicrosoft',
        clientSecret: 'applicationsecretfrommicrosoft',
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/microsoft/callback",
        scope: ['user.read'],
      },
      function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        console.log(profile); //  <---- Log and inspect this!
        User.findOrCreate({ userId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
          return done(err, user);
        });
      }
    ));
```